# Can every even integer be expressed as the difference of two primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Can every even integer be expressed as the difference of two primes?
If so, is there any elementary proof?

Comment: You could strengthen this to "Every even integer can be expressed as the difference of a pair of *consecutive* primes" or "Every even integer can be expressed as the difference of *an infinite number* of pairs of primes", or even to "Every even integer can be expressed as the difference of an infinite number of pairs of consecutive primes".  They are all open questions.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A020483

Comment: @Charles: seen it.

Comment: Isn't this an implication of Goldbach's conjecture being true?

Comment: @AnantSaxena why?

Answer (score 20):

This is listed as an open question at the Prime Pages: http://primes.utm.edu/notes/conjectures/

Comment: The page you're linking to is a bit too old -- the Odd Golbach Conjecture is already proved ([in May $2013$](https://plus.google.com/+TerenceTao27/posts/8qpSYNZFbzC)) and the page doesn't say so, but it's still a fair enough source.

Answer (score 16):

This follows from [Schinzel's conjecture H](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H). Consider the polynomials $x$ and $x+2k$. Their product equals $2k+1$ at 1 and $4(k+1)$ at 2, which clearly do not have any common divisors. So if Schinzel's conjecture holds, there are infinitely many numbers $n$ such that the polynomials are both prime at $n$, and so subtracting gives the result.

Comment: This proof is from Sierpinski's Elementary Theory of Numbers (the second edition of which was edited by Schinzel)