# What is name of conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Every even integer can be expressed as the difference of two primes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28247/every-even-integer-can-be-expressed-as-the-difference-of-two-primes)

there is one conjecture that I do not know what they are called. This is:

Every even number can be always written as the difference between two prime numbers. Could you please help me to know what it is called?

Regards,

Comment: Do you mean difference of two prime numbers or sum of two prime numbers.

Comment: Answered in the comments here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/111196/what-is-the-name-of-a-conjecture

Answer (score 1):

[Polignac's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture) is what you want. It goes further, stating that there are infinately many *prime gaps* of size $n$ for every even integer $n$.