# Are there prime gaps of every size?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it true that for every even natural number $k$ there exists some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g_n = p_{n+1} - p_n = k$?

I don't know how to approach the problem at all, and in fact I don't even know enough about prime gaps to even form a conjecture as to the answer. I feel like the answer is "yes", but only because that would be "nicer" than having some even integers never appear in sequence of prime gaps.

I hope it's not an unsolved problem!

Edit: My question is distinct from Polignac's Conjecture, since I ask if there is *at least one* prime gap, instead of *infinitely many* prime gaps, for every size.

Comment: Do you have a source? I would like to read more about it if it is an open problem.

Comment: I think that it is an unsolved problem known as [Polignac's Conjecture](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjKi6KgrNPKAhXQv44KHQ-JAI0QFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPolignac%27s_conjecture&usg=AFQjCNFX16KSCbsrvZet0tL6NuVETbNW-Q).

Comment: @user170039 my question is distinct from Polignac's Conjecture. I ask if there is _at least one_ prime gap of every size, not _infinitely many_ prime gaps of every size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears to be open if every even number is the difference of two primes, let alone consecutive primes. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28247/29123) is a m.se question mentioning that and an mo question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111196/name-of-a-conjecture-on-difference-of-prime-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

For $n$ a positive integer, the numbers $$(n+1)!+2,(n+1)!+3,..,(n+1)!+n+1$$ are $n$ consecutive composite integers. Does this help ?

Comment: No, this doesn't help.  OP asked about some pair of primes that have a given difference.  Finding a long stretch of non-primes does not speak to this at all.

Comment: I think it's unfair to say that this "does not speak to this at all".  This result is clearly related, for instance, anytime (n+1)!-1 and (n+1)! + (n+2) are prime this would give a solution for k = n+3.