# There's a simple proof that there's no limit on the size of prime gaps. Is there a simple proof that every possible size is represented?

Tags: prime-numbers

This is similar to a question that has been asked but I am asking for something slightly different. It's been asked "are there prime gaps of every (even) size?" My question is, is there a simple proof that there are prime gaps of every (even) size? I'm not actually asking for the proof, and I'd prefer not to read such a proof right now*. So in your answer, if you do provide a proof, first please indicate whether there's a simple proof or not so I can stop there.

By "simple proof" I mean something like the simplicity of the proof that prime gaps can be arbitrarily large--just using math a smart middle schooler could understand, and just taking up a paragraph or two or so.

Thank you!

*Don't want to read it right now because I'd like to figure it out for myself if I can. I just figured out the proof that they can be arbitrarily large, and realized that I had *not* proven that every possible size of prime gap actually exists, so I'd like to do that as well.

Comment: Highly unlikely, considering that many basic results in number theory require complex analysis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there prime gaps of every size?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634110/are-there-prime-gaps-of-every-size) - found in the "Related" section on the right. Note an answer links to [Can every even integer be expressed as the difference of two primes?](/q/28247), where an [answer](/a/28249) there links to [Prime Conjectures and Open Questions](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/conjectures/), where the $3$rd item states the more general "Every even number is the difference of two primes" is still open.

Comment: John, like I said, I'm not asking "are there prime gaps of every size," I'm asking "is there a simple proof" of that proposition, and I'm _not_ asking what the proof is (and would prefer not to know for now).

Comment: @user3752935 Note that being an open question (i.e., a conjecture) means, by definition, that there are *no* proofs (at least, any generally accepted by the math community), simple or otherwise, of the statement being either true or false.

Comment: Is it an open question?

Comment: "It appears to be open if every even number is the difference of two primes" In other words, no one knows the answer to your question, let alone a simple proof. There isn't even a complicated proof. No one knows if there are prime gaps of every size or if there are not prime gaps of every size.

Comment: That answers it! Thanks.

Comment: What I have found with number theory is that there are *lots* of open problems in number theory. It is not hard to come up with a question that is an open problem in number theory. I guess that's what makes number theory exciting to some people.

Comment: Whether every even prime gap occurs is unknown. It is conjectured this is the case. The best known result is that infinite many prime gaps do not exceed $246$ , so one prime gap upto this limit must occur infinite many often. But this is a very deep result without an easy proof.

Comment: Even worse , it is unknown whether for every even positive integer $k$ , there are primes $p,q$ with $q-p=k$