# Should Goldbach's Conjecture be restated thus? *Every integer $>3$ can be expressed as the average of two primes.*

Tags: goldbachs-conjecture

Yes, *every*, not just *even*.

If a number is the average (or difference) of two primes, by doubling the number it has a partition of those two primes. So, for example, $(7+31)/2=19$ becomes $7+31=2*19=38$.

Since every $n*2$ is even, GC has an underappreciated claim upon every odd n > 3 (including every prime). No other conjecture is required.

[CSV of first 100,000: int, diff, p1, p2, type](http://questafi.net/numbers/100000%20pairs.csv)

Comment: Sure, the statement you've given is equivalent to GC, but I see no reason why it would engender a better understanding; in particular, why do you think that it is *not* already understood as having central importance?

Comment: I don't think it's generally understood. For example, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28247/can-every-even-integer-be-expressed-as-the-difference-of-two-primes. However, I'll remove that last sentence. Thanks.

Comment: For strict equivalence, you should say every integer $>1$.

Comment: The equivalence of the two statements is interesting, but trivial to prove. Therefore I don't see any reason to change the original because there's really no tangible advantage in stating it this way.

Comment: Isn't it significant because it proves, also trivially, that there must be pairs of primes (albeit overlapping)? One between $3$ and $\frac{n}{2}$ and one between $\frac{n}{2}$ and $n$.

Comment: In fact this formulation is valid for every integer>1, as numbers 2 and 3 can be written in this form. I asked a very similar question last year and it was deleted I don't know why. I wonder how to recover the text for me.