# Has it been proven that the set of a all $\pm$ odd prime gaps equals $2 \Bbb{Z}$?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, ideals, integers

Let $P_o$ be $\pm$ odd primes and define a basis for open sets as $D(p) = \{ \pm(p-x) : x \geq p, x \in P_o\}$.

*Proof*: have $D(p \cup q) = D(p) \cap D(q)$ since $\pm (p-x) \in D(p \cup q) \iff x \geq p $ and $ x \geq q$ and 
$x \in P_o \iff x - p, p- x \in \{ \pm (p-x) : x \geq p\} \cap \{ \pm (p-x) : x\geq q\} = D(p) \cap D(q)$.

Therefore $D(\text{infinite set}) = \varnothing$ and so is $\bigcup\limits_{p \in P_o} D(p) = 2 \Bbb{Z}$?

$M = (\subset \Bbb{Z}, \cup, \cdot)$ forms a $\Bbb{Z}$-semimodule with elementwise multiplication by $\Bbb{Z}$, and $D : M \to N=(\subset\Bbb{Z}, \cap, \cdot)$ (where $D$ is defined more generally) is a semimodule hom.

Let $D$ be the more general one and let $D(x) \cap P_O$ be the odd prime one.

$D(\bigcup\limits_{x} ax) = a\bigcap\limits_{x} D(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The inclusion $2 \mathbb Z \subseteq \bigcup_{p \in P_0} D(p)$ is equivalent to [Schinzel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H), which has not been proven yet. See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28247/can-every-even-integer-be-expressed-as-the-difference-of-two-primes).