# Is every even integer the sum or difference of two primes?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

The *sum* bit is Goldbach's conjecture, which is open. The *difference* bit seems to be open as well (e.g. according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28247/can-every-even-integer-be-expressed-as-the-difference-of-two-primes) source).

What if we allow the alternative? More precisely, has the following (seemingly) weaker question been resolved or is it open too?

Given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, do there always exist (not necessarily distinct) primes $p_1$, $p_2$ such that $2n\in\{p_1+p_2, p_1-p_2\}$?

Comment: This is most likely an open problem as well.

Comment: (Seemingly) weaker does not help if there is no technique for a proof for most of these questions.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Agreed. I'm not trying to crack Goldbach, I'm just wondering.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Adding non-linear alternatives (like sum of prime and semiprime) seems to have made things easier. Or are you saying that adding linear ones won't make it easier? There are indeed not many linear ones that can be added, seeing as everything is a sum of 5-6 primes.

Comment: Yes, I am saying that proving every even integer is the sum of two primes $p+q$ or a sum $p+3q$ doesn't make things easier. Or $p-q$. But I am not completely sure, of course.